# matching data in two tables if match..Display the Name and msg

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in `mysql`. Following is my script.

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost",'root','');
mysql_select_db('test');

$sql    = "SELECT data_student.name,ozekimessagein.msg 
            FROM ozekimessagein,data_student
            WHERE ozekimessagein.sender=data_student.sender 
            ORDER BY ozekimessagein.msg";

$res=mysql_query($sql);
$cn=mysql_num_rows($res);
for($x=0;$x<$cn;$x++)
{
    list($name,$msg)=mysql_fetch_row($res);
    echo "<li>$name,$msg";
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

this should display the name from table `data_student` table and the message from `ozekimessagein` as long as the sender in `data_student` table match with the sender in the `ozekimessagein` table. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Off Topic : check this [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* function in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
SELECT 

data_student.name,
ozekimessagein.msg 

FROM ozekimessagein 
inner join data_student     on ozekimessagein.sender=data_student.sender 

ORDER BY ozekimessagein.msg
```

Comment: i already try such code..still it doesn't work. . it shpuld display for example **Name**: Message . .But this paramaters will be fetch from different tables as long as sender from ozekimessagein table match with the sender in data_student table.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <?php
  $conn=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('test');

 $sql    = "

   SELECT s.name AS names, o.msg AS msgs
  FROM ozekimessagein o
  INNER JOIN data_student s
   ON o.sender = s.sender
   ORDER BY s.name";

  $res=mysql_query($sql);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

 echo "<li>".$row['names']." : ".$row['msgs']."</li>";
     }
  mysql_close($conn);
  ?>
```

Comment: i did try your code. .But unfortunately nothing appears on the browser.

Comment: try make this in top and see what error u are getting `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: can u post your sql table also ?

Comment: im currently using a xammp server.. I already check mysql tables(ozekimessagein & data_student) they both contains a sender column, it goes along with the code. i don't know where the error is. As i try to reload the page, i end up nothing in the webpage.

Comment: try put this under `mysql_select_db` to see if it connected to your database `if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}`

Comment: it says there is an error on while condition .. supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource.

Comment: still nothing appears on the webpage..anyway thank you peter. . :)